# In CakePHP what is the correct way to preselect current belongsTo for add?

Tags: php, cakephp

There is Payments that belongsTo Salaries (Payments.salary_id).

In Salaries/view.php I have "Add new payment" link:

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('Add new payment'), ['controller'=>'Payments','action' => 'add', $salary->id], ['class' => 'side-nav-item']) ?>
```

In PaymentsController.php:

```
public function add($salary_id = null)
{
    $payment = $this->Payments->newEmptyEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $payment = $this->Payments->patchEntity($payment, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Payments->save($payment)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The payment has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Salaries','action' => 'view', $payment->salary_id]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The payment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    if ($salary_id) {
        $salaries = $this->Payments->Salaries->find('list')
        ->where(['Salaries.id LIKE' => $salary_id])
        ->contain(['Employees'])
        ->all();
    } else {
        $salaries = $this->Payments->Salaries->find('list', ['contain' => ['Employees']])->all();
    }
    $this->set(compact('payment', 'salaries'));
}
```

When the salary_id is passed to the Payments/add.php, only this Salary is shown in the select menu. If there is no salary_id, then all the Salaries are shown in the select menu. The Salaries needs to have Employees as there is displayField that will get data from Employee.

This part in the Payments/add.php:

```
echo $this->Form->control('salary_id');
```

Seems to get the displayField from $salaries (array) by magic.

The questions are:

- What would be the correct way to pass the current salary_id to the Payment/add.php if this way is not the correct way?
- What would be the correct or cleaner way to preselect (preferably enforce) the given Salary in the Payments/add.php select menu (and allow any of the Salaries to be selected if there is no Salary given)?

I am new to CakePHP so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably should do is to:

1. Always pass all salaries to the view, ie do not take the ID into account in the controller.
2. Pass the `$salary_id` variable to the view, and use it for the control's `default` option, it will then use this as the value for selection unless there's a value for it in the current request (for example in the POST data).

```
// ...
$salaries = $this->Payments->Salaries->find('list')->contain('Employees')->all();
$this->set(compact('payment', 'salaries', 'salary_id'));
```

```php
echo $this->Form->control('salary_id', ['default' => $salary_id]);
```

On a side note, containing data when using a `list` finder will not add any of the contained data to the results, so unless the contain causes an `INNER` join that you'd want to use for filtering data, there should be no need for it (consider using `innerJoinWith()` instead if you want to filter things).

See also

- **[Views > Helpers > Form > Common Options For Specific Controls](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#common-options-for-specific-controls)**